# ES6 Module export default syntax

Tags: javascript, jshint, ecmascript-harmony, esprima

I'm using the es6-module-transpiler, esprima and JSHint with `esnext: true` options.  JSHint complains when I put:

```
export default = { some: 'thing', other: 'thing' };
```

But esprima complains when I use

```
export default { some: 'thing', other: 'thing' };
```

The [spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-exports) says

> `export default AssignmentExpression ;`

Which makes me think that JSHint needs updating and esprima is properly bombing out because there isn't an assignment.  Can someone be the deciderer for me here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually an *AssignmentExpression* can be any expression, it's the expression at the top most level, the one that contains all other expressions (see the [spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-expressions)).

However,

```
export default = { some: 'thing', other: 'thing' };
```

really isn't an assignment expression it's a syntax error. If you use the assignment operator in an assignment expression, then you need a left hand side and a right hand side. So something like this would be valid:

```
export default foo = { some: 'thing', other: 'thing' };
```

Just using an object literal should be correct, because, as I said, an *AssignmentExpression* can be *any* expression.

So Esprima seems to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the decidering.  I have [filed an issue](https://code.google.com/p/esprima/issues/detail?id=486) with the esprima project if you are interested in following.